# Is it possible to use reCAPTCHA without iframe and any javascript?

Tags: javascript, security, iframe, recaptcha

For security reasons, we have disabled the iframes and javascript within our web application. Now we would like to implement reCAPTCHA in the login process. I see that it embeds an `iframe` on the page, which is disabled so it cannot be seen. Is there a way of implementing the reCAPTCHA without using `iframe` or javascript?

Answer (score 3):

I was looking at this question for disabled people (i.e blind) who do not have Javascript.

An ugly solution could be to call the ReCaptcha from a server, get the produced HTML, pass it to the browser, submit a form when the user clicks, then submit the user's input from your server, using Javascript.

It looks like Google anyway *explicitely forbids* to call its ReCaptcha APIs from a web server.
This means using ReCaptcha without Javascript is not possible.

For Iframes, I have not tested.

Also, you need to understand that Google and other software providers like to provide javascript SDK because it is easier to maintain. If you hack the inside JS/iframes to directly call an API, it's likely a few months later the JS has changed and your hack is broken...

**However**, you can use ReCaptcha without JS :
[How to hide recaptcha for JavaScript enabled browsers and pass html validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853007/how-to-hide-recaptcha-for-javascript-enabled-browsers-and-pass-html-validation)

Basically following the above link and using the example of user968834